# Is $p(n) = 2^{n²+n-1} - n² - n + 1$ abundant for all $n >1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $p(n)=2^{n²+n-1}-n²-n+1 $, and let $\delta(n)$ be sum of **proper** divisors of $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

After some verifications according to the values of $n>1$  I noticed:

$$\delta(p(n))> p(n)$$

Is there some way to prove that for all $n>1$ : $\delta(p(n))> p(n)$ or is there a counterexample for it?

Note: For some verification [look here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282%5E%285%29%29-5%29%2F%28sumdivisors%28%282%5E%285%29%29-5%29).

Comment: sorry , i don't get attention to 1, now it's fixed

Comment: You still haven't answered the question of whether you are referring to the sum of divisors or the sum of **proper** divisors.  I.e. is $\delta(12) = 1+2+3+4+6+12 = 28$ or is $\delta(12)=1+2+3+4+6=16$?  (where your definition of $\delta(n)$ is now changed to "sum of divisors of $n$").  I.e., in the [link to wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), are you referring to $\sigma_1(n)$ or are you referring to $s(n)$?

Comment: My arithmetic is poor, maybe you can check $n=3$.  By hand is more reliable than Alpha.

Comment: pleas , I meant sum divisors of p(n) not n

Comment: We can't start thinking about $p(n)$ until you adequately define $\delta$ first.  if $\delta=\sigma_1$ the answer is incredibly trivial, if $\delta = s$ then it will require some thought.

Comment: ok, thank you I meant \delta =s

Comment: and I defined delta as a sum of divisors of p(n) , pleas look note . and check link in wolfram alpha for confirmation

Comment: look for the case n=3 , p(3)=291 and see :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282^%2811%29%29-11%29%2F%28sumdivisors%28%282^%2811%29%29-11%29

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: Maybe you intend something other than what is typed in the OP. If $n=3$ then $n^2+n-1$ is $11$  and we are looking at $2037$.

Comment: The sum of proper divisors of $2037$ is $1+3+7+21+97+291+679=1099 < 2037$, as such $\delta(p(3)) = \delta(2011) =1099 \not > 2037 = p(3)$.  I think you are confusing the sum of **proper** divisors ( $s(n)$) and the *sum of divisors* ($\sigma_1(n)$).  Wolframalpha interprets "sum of divisors" as $\sigma_1$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282^%2811%29%29-11%29%2F%28sumdivisors%28%282^%2811%29%29-11%29

Comment: $p(2)=27$ and $\delta(p(n))=1+3+9=13$

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks i thought the sum as \delta_{1}

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Then, the inequality is obviously true.

Answer (score 2):

If referring to the sum of all divisors (which includes the number itself), trivially $\sigma_1(n) > n$ for all $n>1$ since $\sigma_1(n) = 1 + n + (\text{other stuff if n isn't prime or 0 if it is prime}) > n$

This trivially implies that $\sigma_1(p(n))>p(n)$ for all $n$ such that $p(n)>1$.

If your conjecture is instead about the sum of **proper divisors**, i.e., $s(n)$, then the conjecture fails for several small values of $n$.

$s(p(2)) = s(27) = 1+3+9=13 < 27 = p(2)$

$s(p(3)) = s(2037) = 1+3+7+21+97+291+679=1099 < 2037 = p(3)$

It is doubtful that many (if any) values hold true.  This should reiterate the importance of understanding what definitions you and/or your calculator are using.  In this case, keeping track of the difference between "the sum of divisors" and "the sum of proper divisors."

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer